# Scheduled sftp job fails

Tags: cygwin, sftp, openssh, novell

I have Cygwin+OpenSSH installed on Windows XP workstation.

Simple SFTP process (batch file) runs fine when launched from the Command Prompt and fails when launched by a Scheduler from Novell Desktop Management.  Scheduled job uses exactly the same batch file and runs as Interactive User impersonation.

WhoAmI embedded in the batch file returns the same user string.  Cygwin itself called from a scheduled job shows the same user id in the prompt as when launched directly from the dektop icon.

I get the following error from a scheduled sftp job:

```
"Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).  
 Connection closed"
```

Comment: Please post the actual command lines used (both the interactive one and the one used in the batch file).

Comment: Both manual and scheduled process run the same batch file as follows:
   sftp -b scriptfile ftp_id@ftp.server
 where scriptfile have the following commands:
   cd download
   pwd
   lpwd
   put pipeline*.txt.10222009152704
   dir pipeline*.txt.10222009152704
   bye

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with file permissions on the `id_dsa` file.

Apparently though both manual and scheduled processes ran with the same user id, they used different authentication: *domain* vs. *workstation*.